# get some content from my file to string.how can i get

Tags: objective-c, string

NSString *txtFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource: @"/cnuu.rtf" ofType: @"rtf"];

```
NSString *str5=[NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:txtFilePath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
NSLog(@"%@",str5);
```

Comment: RTF is not text, is it (strictly speaking)?

Comment: Remove the `/` from the filename to start with

Answer (score 1):

Although your question isn't really understandable, I guess you should change @"/cnuu.rtf" to @"cnuu" since the ofType: parameter already contains the extension and you are not specifying a path so you don't need the slash.

Answer (score 0):

This is caused because you're reading `/cnuu.rtf.rtf` file, instead of that you need to read `cnuu.rtf`

You need to read either

```
NSString *txtFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource: @"cnuu.rtf" ofType:nil];
```

Or

```
NSString *txtFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource: @"cnuu" ofType: @"rtf"];
```

And the read the content via

```
NSString *content = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:txtFilePath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
NSLog(@"%@", content);
```